# error in retrieving mail through a proxy

Tags: java

we are retrieving mail from gmail server.we could connect to the gmail server without proxy. As there is a proxy setting in our college we couldn't connect to the gmailserver even after setting the system properties. we could connect to gmail.com from our browser but we couldn't connect from our program.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();  
props.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxyhost");  
props.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "proxynumber");  
props.setProperty( "mail.imap.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);  
props.setProperty( "mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
props.setProperty( "mail.imap.port", "993");  
props.setProperty( "mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993");  
props.put("mail.imap.host", "imap.gmail.com");  
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);  

store = session.getStore("imap");  
store.connect(dialog.getServer(),dialog.getUsername(),dialog.getPassword());
```

we get this exception

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: imap.gmail.com 
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:618) 
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291) 
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172) 
at EmailClient.connect(EmailClient.java:373) 
at EmailClient.main(EmailClient.java:475) 
by: java.net.UnknownHostException: imap.gmail.com 
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source 

at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:284) 
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:201) 
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:109) 
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104) 

at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:585)
```

Comment: Are you able to do 'nslookup imap.gmail.com' on the server?  Also what O/S is the server running?

Comment: are you proxying smtp also or just http ?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that your proxy uses NTLM authentication, I've had issues in the past with Java and NTLM authentication. Not sure if it is actually the proxy giving you issues though.

In any which case, instead of using the JavaMail API directly you might want to have a look at using the [GMail API for Java](http://g4j.sourceforge.net/) g4j. It will abstract away most of the complexities of dealing with gmail in general.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

> JavaMail does [not currently support](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#proxy) accessing mail servers
>   through a web proxy server.
>
> If your proxy server supports the SOCKS V4 or V5 protocol  and allows
>   anonymous connections, and you're using JDK 1.5 or newer and JavaMail
>   1.4.5 or newer, you can configure a SOCKS proxy